# Getting Ubuntu to boot from a different drive

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HDD (I have a SSD for Windows and a HDD for games and programs) after shrinking it and making four partitions for Ubuntu. After installation it booted into Ubuntu fine, but after shutting down Ubuntu I can´t boot into it anymore; it just boots straight into Windows.

I changed the boot order to boot from HDD first, but then I just got a PXE ROM startup and then straight to Windows. I also tried the EasyBCD to add an entry, but EBCD just gave me a UEFI error.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What brand/model system? Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode on gpt partitioned HDD(assuming Windows is UEFI)? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and gpt partitioning: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: I'm not sure if this works under multiple drives. But did you try holding `Shift` while booting, so you can access grub?

Answer (score -1):

Did you set Ubuntu’s boot manager as the default boot device? http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/05/31/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-windows-7-on-a-pc-with-2-hdds-and-uefi-firmware/

I also found some good info here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1640178

I hope you get it working!

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, they become useless if the links get obsolete and people have to leave the site to find their answers. You should instead include all important information directly into your post, then it's okay to add the link as reference.